# How to convert a long string to multiple strings and save

Tags: bash, shell

Below script saves a long strings in a `err_$(date).txt` file. I would like to convert the long strings into smaller strings with new lines. In below given code, in `err_$(date).txt` file I get this text: `Error1 in Machine 1 \n\n Error2 in Machine 1 \n\n Error2 in Machine 2 \n\n`. I would like to save  a new strings each time `\n\n` is there. But without `\n\n`. Each next line should only have the error for example line 1 should have `Error1 in Machine 1`, line 2 should have `Error2 in Machine 1` and so on. I hope the question is clear.

```
#!/bin/sh

if grep -R "Error1 in Machine 1 " /home/new/Report.txt
then
echo "Error1 found in Machine 1"
strg="${strg} Error1 found in Machine 1 \n\n"
else
echo "No Error found"
fi


if grep -R "Error2 in Machine 1" /home/new/Report.txt
then
echo "Error2 found in Machine 1"
strg="${strg} Error2 in Machine 1 \n\n"
else
echo "No Error found"
fi


if grep -R "Error2 in Machine 2" /home/new/Report.txt
then
echo "Error2 found in Machine 2"
strg="${strg} Error2 in Machine 2 \n\n"
else
echo "No Error found"
fi

whiptail --title "Report Error" --msgbox "${strg}" 24 30
echo "${strg}" >| /home/new/err_$(date).txt
```

Answer (score -2):

You might want to try something like this:

```
while IFS="\n\n" read LINE;
do
    #do your stuff with $LINE
done < input.file
```